# What "aliased ptr with a non-none lp" means in rust

Tags: rust

For the following code:

```
import io::*;
import to_str::*;

impl <T : to_str copy> of to_str for @[mut T] {
    fn to_str() -> str {
        let tmp = copy self;
        tmp.map(|x| { x.to_str() }).to_str()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println((@[mut 1, 2, 3]).to_str());
}
```

I am getting an error:

```
example.rs:7:8: 7:11 error: internal compiler error: aliased ptr with a non-none lp
example.rs:7         tmp.map(|x| { x.to_str() }).to_str()
                     ^~~
```

How to fix it? And what `aliased ptr with a non-none lp` means anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal compiler errors are always bugs in Rust. The best thing to do when you see one is to submit an issue at https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues that includes the code that causes the error.

As far as how to work around the bug, what if you use `~[mut T]` instead of `@[mut T]`? We just recently added `@` vectors, and a lot of the library code for working with them is still missing.

Comment: Ha, I just found https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/2926 and saw that you already filed the bug and found the workaround. Nice work!

Comment: My report was a duplicate, original bug https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/2797 was just closed. This ICE is not appears anymore in recent (0.3 (30d94fe 2012-07-17 22:16:55 -0400)) rustc. Thank you!